# Flask gunicorn to API endpoint mapping possible?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, worker

I am running my flask app on a single staging server. I am using gunicorn to define my app settings like number of workers, timeout values etc. There are 3 endpoints for my app. can i make gunicorn worker settings in such a way that

3 workers for /test

3 workers for /test1

3 workers for /test2

4000+ requests hitting the /test endpoint keep all the workers busy for a long time as a result anyone querying the other endpoints, have to wait for a very long time till the workers get available. Is there any way to map certain endpoints to certain workers? Adding more instances is not a solution here coz its a stg environment. I cant add them. How can i optimize? I am using a quad core linux machine and currently set my number of workers to 50.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd generally question if this is a *real* issue for you. If those 4000+ requests are simply theory, then keep it simple and scale later.

But! If you're keen on trying this, you'll need something to sit alongside gunicorn. gunicorn runs off a master loop which manages the list of running workers and pushes work appropriately. I imagine you could build a gunicorn [worker configuration](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#master) that'd spawn workers based on function but that seems overly complex.

Thus, I'd recommend looking at [nginx load balancing](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html), which allows you to easily define a variety of upstreams and route (`proxy_pass`) requests to specific upstreams.